# Ecoomerce tracking are not displaying in google anayltic (Magento 2.2)

Tags: magento2.2

I have enabled the "Google Analytics" in magento 2 website(version 2.2.0) and also enabled the eCommerce setting google analytic but still no eCommerce related information displaying.

As I have investigate I found order tracking data always remain blank that is why no eCommerce information is displaying in google analytic.

```
"ordersTrackingData": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ json_encode($block->getOrdersTrackingData()) ?>,
```

But the issue if we resolve this, then information will start displaying only for success page because  getOrdersTrackingData always check orderId (vendor\magento\module-google-analytics\Block\Ga.php).

```
$orderIds = $this->getOrderIds();
    if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
        return;
    }
```

How we can display analytic for product, cart and payment page? Is the feature is not available with default magento and do we need to add some other module for this.

Comment: Order ids is set from observer but never displaying on html files so never google tag generated for order success page.

Answer (score 0):

This is magento 2.2 bug which is listed on github https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14951